# Unexplained behavior when using Entity Framework Code First with List<string>.Contains method

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**The Problem**

We have been experiencing timeout errors on some of our queries and after investigation and testing, we have narrowed the issue down to the dynamic Sql query that is created by Entity Framework Code First.

**Background**

We are using Entity Framework v4.3.1, Code First model
Code written with VS 2010 Premium

We have a table in the database defined as follows with ID being the PK

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reference](
    [DocumentID] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DetailID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TransactionSet] [char](5) NULL,
    [Qualifier] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [ReferenceID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

We have an entity class defined as follows to correspond to the table:

```
public class Reference
{
    public string DocumentID { get; set; }
    public string DetailID { get; set; }
    public string TransactionSet { get; set; }
    public string Qualifier { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

We have a data context defined as follows (partial class shown for brevity):

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("Name=DataContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Reference> References { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Reference>().HasKey(pk => pk.ID);
    }
}
```

Finally the calling code is as follows:

```
private List<Reference> getDocumentReferences(List<string> documentIds)
{
    List<Reference> result = null;

    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            var q = context.References.Where(r => documentIds.Contains(r.DocumentID) && r.Qualifier == "AFN");

            Logger.WriteLogEntry("Sql query:\r\n {0}", q.ToString());   //Added to see the query generated by EF

            result = q.ToList();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Description**

When the code is executed, the following query is sent to Sql Server:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[DocumentID] AS [DocumentID], 
    [Extent1].[DetailID] AS [DetailID], 
    [Extent1].[TransactionSet] AS [TransactionSet], 
    [Extent1].[Qualifier] AS [Qualifier], 
    [Extent1].[ReferenceID] AS [ReferenceID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
FROM [dbo].[Reference] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[DocumentID] IN (N'A2014011300028343869701A020',N'A2014011300028343869701A021')) AND (N'AFN' = [Extent1].[Qualifier])
```

Notice that since the code uses the Contains method of a List, that it is translated by EF into an IN clause in the sql query.  Each string in the IN clause is prefixed with 'N' indicating a unicode string.  Since the DocumentID column in the table is VARCHAR (not NVARCHAR), Sql must do an implicit conversion in order to execute the query.  After investigation and testing, we found that in this case, it will not select the relevant indexes which results in a table scan and often a timeout exception.

We discovered that by *removing* the N prefix from the query, the proper index was used and the query ran orders of magnitude faster.

So in order to make EF not prefix the strings with N, I added the two lines below to the data context class in the OnModelCreating method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Reference>().Property(r => r.DocumentID).HasColumnType("VARCHAR");
modelBuilder.Entity<Reference>().Property(r => r.Qualifier).HasColumnType("VARCHAR");
```

And when I tested this on my local machine, it had the desired effect.  The query that was submitted to Sql Server was as follows.  Note that the N prefix is not included on the strings in the IN clause:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[DocumentID] AS [DocumentID], 
    [Extent1].[DetailID] AS [DetailID], 
    [Extent1].[TransactionSet] AS [TransactionSet], 
    [Extent1].[Qualifier] AS [Qualifier], 
    [Extent1].[ReferenceID] AS [ReferenceID], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
FROM [dbo].[Reference] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[DocumentID] IN ('A2014011300028343869701A020','A2014011300028343869701A021')) AND ('AFN' = [Extent1].[Qualifier])
```

I thought my problems were solved, but when I deployed this code to the test environment, the N prefixes were not removed and I cannot figure out why.

I can work around the problem by creating the Sql queries manually, but I have a few more queries in this program that need similar changes and it would be easier if I only had to change the OnModelCreating method instead of creating each query manually.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this is occurring?

Incidentally, my local machine uses Sql Server 2008, whereas the test environment (and production) uses Sql 2005.  I'm not sure if that can affect the query produced by EF since my impression is that the query is generated before being submitted to the database.

**Update**

If I execute the code *on my box* against the test database, it works correctly.  If the code executes *on the test box*, it doesn't even though they both are hitting the same database.

**Update 2**

The code runs successfully depending on where it is executed.

```
EXE Location  |  EXE Executed From  |  Database Server (Version)  |  Result
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
My Box        |  My Box             |  My Box (2008)              |  Success
Test Server   |  My Box             |  Test DB Server (2005)      |  Success
Test Server   |  Test Server        |  Test DB Server (2005)      |  Fail
```

It seems logical, based on the results above, that there is something on my local box that is different than on the test machine.  But I don't know how to diagnose it.  The only difference that I can think of is that my box has .Net 4.5 installed and the test server does not.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to correct this behavior with [`DataAnnotations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx):

```
public class Reference
{
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar"), MaxLength(100)]
    public string DocumentID { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar"), MaxLength(50)]
    public string DetailID { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "char"), MaxLength(5)]
    public string TransactionSet { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar"), MaxLength(80)]
    public string Qualifier { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string ReferenceID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(80)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

EF6 onwards, you'd be able to change this `DbContext`-wide using [`Custom Conventions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using annotations.  I though if I did it in the OnModelCreating method, that I didn't need the annotations.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only had partial success.  The part of the query with the Qualifier column did not include the N prefix, but the values inside the IN clause still had the N prefix.  Could the fact that the version of SQL server on my local machine, test environment, and production are different have any effect?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm going to setup an environment with EF 4.3.1 and figure out what I missed.

Comment: If I execute the code *on my box* against the test database, it works correctly.  If the code executes *on the test box*, it doesn't even though they both are hitting the same database.

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate this behavior. I believe your suspicion about the environment differences is playing a part. Unfortunately, I don't have an instance of SqlSever2005 handy. I'll keep looking and report any findings.